# Не вызывается метод для URLScheme в AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Пытаюсь настроить URL Scheme для передачи данных в приложение, в AppDelegate добавил метод

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        print("Yeap")
        return true
    }
}
```

Прописал в info.plist[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю Эмулятор, захожу в Safari, в адресной строке пишу

```
lp://test
```

Появилось сообщение, о том что нужно ли открыть приложение %NameOfApplication%

Соглашаюсь, меня перекидывает в приложение. В консоле ничего не появилось, соответственно метод application не вызвался.

Как мне получить данные, с помощью такого способа?

P.S.
В консоле после смены приложения появляется такое сообщение:

```
Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1 (0x1), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.
```

Приложение "пустое", ничего кроме описанного в тикете не добавлял.

Xcode 11.2

Работа под IOS 13.1